# How to get started on this?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

if i provide a site name and a list name , the script should delete the items in the list and then delete the list? is this possible in powershell or javascript? can anyone help me?
This is for SharePoint online so how to make below code to work for SharePoint online?

```````````````
##  SP URL
Write-Host "Provide SharePoint URL:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$webURL = Read-Host
$web = Get-SPweb $webURL
 
## LIST NAME
Write-Host "Enter name of the list:" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$listName = Read-Host
$list = $web.lists[$listName]
 
## SET QUERY
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$query.RowLimit = 1000
$query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>"
$query.ViewFieldsOnly = $true
 
 
## EXECUTE
do
{
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
 
    foreach ($item in $listItems)
    {
        Write-Host "Deleting Item - $($item.Id)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $list.GetItemById($item.Id).delete()
    }

   
 
#Reset the "Allow Deletion" Flag
$list.AllowDeletion = $true
$list.Update()
 
$list.Delete()



}
while ($null -eq $query.ListItemCollectionPosition)
 
Write-Host "Script finished." -ForegroundColor Green ``````````````
```````````````

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Looks like you already have some code - why not start by executing it and observe whether it does what you expect? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting items from specified list or/and the list itself is possible both using PowerShell and javascript.

- For the javascript you may either use REST API calls for that or JSOM. Here you may find examples how to use JSOM to perform basic CRUD operations -> [How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v=office.14)). Please be aware that in order for JSOM to work it needs a SP context which may be created only when the JS is executed in the context of SharePoint (so for example on a SharePoint page)
- as for PowerShell you may use PnP PowerShell cmdlets for it. [Here is the MSDN article how to get the PnP PowerShell for SharePoint Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) and [connect to a site](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/authentication.html) and here are the commands you were asking for: the [Remove-PnPListItem](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Remove-PnPListItem.html) and [Remove-PnPList](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Remove-PnPList.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use pnp powershell:

Delete item:

```
Get-PnPList -Identity Lists/MyList | Get-PnPListItem -PageSize 100 -ScriptBlock { Param($items) 
$items.Context.ExecuteQuery() } | % {$_.DeleteObject()}
```

Delete list:

```
Remove-PnPList -Identity "test5" -Force
```

Delete the entire list directly, the item will also be deleted.

Download pnp powershell [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps).